# Passing Fortran integer array to C subroutine only first element passed

Tags: c, arrays, fortran, fortran-iso-c-binding

I am trying to pass an integer array from Fortran to C but I can only pass the first element of the array.

I have the test program below which reproduces the error. Where am I going wrong?

```
program test
   use foo

   integer (kind=c_int), allocatable :: hgmu_dose(:)
   allocate (hgmu_dose(0:10))

HGMU_dose(0)=22
HGMU_dose(1)=2
HGMU_dose(2)=3
HGMU_dose(3)=4
HGMU_dose(4)=5
HGMU_dose(5)=6
HGMU_dose(6)=7
HGMU_dose(7)=8
HGMU_dose(8)=9
HGMU_dose(9)=10
HGMU_dose(10)=11

print *, "HGMU_dose=", hgmu_dose 

call  test_interface(hgmu_dose)

end program

module foo
  use ISO_C_Binding 

  implicit none 
  interface  
    subroutine test_interface(dose) bind(C,name="INTERFACE")
      import :: c_int
      import :: c_double
      import :: c_char

      integer (kind=c_int), allocatable :: dose(:)
    end subroutine  
  end interface

end module foo
```

With

```
#include "interface.h"

 namespace interface
{

  extern "C" void INTERFACE (int dose[NDIM])
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < NDIM; i++)
      cout << " dose[" << i << "] = " << dose[i] << endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you show use `interface.h` or at least where `NDIM` is defined?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues here.

The first is in your definition of the test_interface, interface. You do not need or want the `allocatable` keyword.

```
subroutine test_interface(dose) bind(C,name="INTERFACE")

  import :: c_int

  integer (kind=c_int) :: dose(:)

end subroutine
```

The second is the `iso_c_binding` will pass by reference. So when you define your function in C it should be accepting a pointer to an array:

```
void INTERFACE (int *dose[NDIM])
```

Lastly as a side note, you don't have to define your Fortran array as starting from 0. You can use the Fortran normally starting from 1.

Comment: The C declaration is ok - it is just the allocatable attribute in the fortran interface block that is problematic.

Comment: @IanH are you sure? As that's not what I'm seeing. When `int dose[NDIM]` the `cout` is giving me `dose[0] = -1581234144`, `dose[1] = 32712` etc. While if I pass it as `int *dose[NDIM]` and then print with `(*dose)[i]`, I get the correct values `dose[0] = 22`, `dose[1] = 2`

Comment: I am sure.  Note also that the dummy argument in the Fortran interface cannot be assumed shape either - you need to change the array specification from `(:)` to `(*)` or, if the value of NDIM is available on the Fortran side, `(NDIM)`.  (Later standards than F2008 may permit things such as deferred shape and assumed shape arguments, but then there are substantial changes on what the C code needs to do.)

Comment: thanks for your comments - i have got a test example working for the complete set of parameters i need to pass from fortran to                                                                   but when I use the same code in my much larger and more complicated code it crashes with access violation error - one of my favourites. i wanted to post the complete test example here but it wouldn't let me.

Comment: fixed my problem! - there was a setting in visual studio to define whether string lengths are passed immediately after the string or at the end of the arguement list - i had the wrong setting