# Pass pointer-to-member-function for class without copy constructor into Fortran

Tags: c++, c++11, fortran, function-pointers

I have a call to a Fortran function, the first argument of which is a function, for which I would like to use a C++ member-function of the form,

`void Obj::memberF(double* x,double* res)`

with `Obj` having the copy-constructor disabled (and this becomes important as shown below).

The Fortran subroutine is of the form

`subroutine solve(f,len,x)`

with `f` taking two arguments, `x` and `rhs`, both of which are real arrays. `len` stands for the length of these arrays.

(Essentially, need to call the residue function in a non-linear solver library)

For this purpose, irrespective of the eventual C++ approach, we will need a binder and is as follows

*binder.f90*

```
SUBROUTINE cpp_solve(cpp_f,len,x) BIND(C, NAME='cpp_solve')
  USE, INTRINSIC :: iso_c_binding, ONLY : c_int, c_float
  INTERFACE
    SUBROUTINE cpp_f(x,rhs) BIND(C)
      USE, INTRINSIC :: iso_c_binding, ONLY : c_float
      REAL(c_float) :: x(:)
      REAL(c_float) :: rhs(:)
    END SUBROUTINE cpp_f
  END INTERFACE
  INTEGER(c_int) :: len
  REAL(c_float) :: x(len)
  CALL solve(cpp_f,len,x)
END SUBROUTINE cpp_solve
```

For the C++ program, first, a wrapper is needed for these functions

*wrap.h*

```
extern "C" {
  void cpp_f(double*,double*);
  void cpp_solve(void (Obj::*cpp_f)(double*,double*),int*,double*);
}
```

The main program is as follows

*main.cpp*

```
#include "wrap.h"

int main {
  int len = 2;
  std::vector<double> x(len);
  // Multiple lines to initialize foo
  // Creating a global Obj is not feasible
  // ...
  Obj current_object(foo);

  // WHAT GOES HERE? 

  // cpp_solve(...,len,x);
}
```

Below are a few approaches I've considered, starting with recent C++ features,

1) Note that the copy-constructor of `Obj` has been disabled for other reasons and is the constraint. This prevents me from using `std::bind` to attach the current instance and obtain a function pointer.

2) Also, defining another function `extra_function(Obj& obj, double*,...)` and then using a lambda to just return `obj.memberF` is not an option either, as that would require me to specify a capture, given the custom object and I need a function pointer only.

3) A simpler option would be to just obtain the member function pointer and then, pass the current instance as follows

```
typedef void (Obj::*fptr)(double*,double*);

fptr current_fPointer = &Obj::memberF;
cpp_solve(current_object.*current_fPointer,len,x);
```

This gives me the 'invalid use of non-static member function' error.

Is there an alternative approach I could use to obtain the function pointer?

TBH, I'm actually trying to call a Fortran 77 routine using these C++11 features, so that's some retrofuturism.

Comment: If you want `cpp_f` to be C interoperable by the current Fortran standard, the dummy arguments cannot be assumed shape.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that.

Comment: Have you considered using `std::function` initialized by lambda e.g.: `std::function<void(double* , double*)> foo = [&current_object](double* len, double* x) { current_object.memberF(len, x); };` ?

Comment: @francescalus do you have suggestions for how the length of arrays can be conveyed to the arguments in cpp_f? The prototype cannot be changed as it is part of the library.

Comment: @W.F. Are you sure this will not give a `std::function` object but a function pointer, given that there is a non-default capture

Comment: If that's an accurate interface for `cpp_f` then you can find examples of how such a function can be interoperable in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34561835/3157076).

Answer (score 2):

If this is a single threaded program, a pragmatic approach could use a global pointer variable with an extra function

```
static Obj *g_obj;

static void extra_func(double *x1, double *x2)
{
    g_obj->memberF(x1, x2);
}

void call_f77(Obj *o1, int *len, double *x)
{
    g_obj = o1;
    cpp_solve(extra_func, len, x);
}
```

---

Another approach, if you can modify the Fortran code (and Fortran transparently can pass object pointers somehow), you may tunnel the relevant object through Fortran to the `extra_func`, e.g.

```
static void extra_func(void *p, double *x1, double *x2)
{
    Obj *obj = static_cast<Obj*>(p);
    obj->memberF(x1, x2);
}

void call_f77(Obj *o1, int *len, double *x)
{
    cpp_solve(extra_func, o1, len, x);
}
```

and in Fortran (please forgive me, I've never seen any Fortran code):

```fortran
SUBROUTINE solve(cpp_f, obj, len, x)
...
CALL cpp_f(obj, x, rhs)
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the approach and I had considered it actually. Unfortunately, I cannot create a global `Obj` as it will need `foo`, which involves multiple objects to be initialized, which make up the bulk of the program. I've edited my question to clarify this.

Comment: Not a global object, but a global pointer to the currently used/active object.

Comment: Worth a shot. I will wait for other answers though, given the presence of a global variable.