# How to use structures with pointers in Fortran like in C++?

Tags: fortran

I have been using C++ for several years. Then I decided to use Fortran for better math performance. In C++ I have the following structure which I use everywhere:

```
structure     BitMap{
char*     rgba;         // pointer to the color array
int       w, h;};       // dimension of my bitmap
```

In Fortran, on the other hand:

```
Program Bitmap_p
implicit none
type BitMap
character :: rgba(*) ! like a pointer to bitmap array (colors and alpha)
integer:: w  ! bitmap width
integer:: h  ! bitmap height
endtype BitMap
endprogram Bitmap_p
```

However, when compiling this, the compilers states:

> 1. f90 (4): error #6530: The array spec for this component must be of explicit shape and each bound must be an initialization expression. [RGBA]

Comment: Sorry, please, for my English. I'm trying to avoid grammar  mistakes. But it difficult for me yet.

Comment: A pointer is something quite different from a string in both C++ and Fortran.  You've translated a pointer in C++ into a string in Fortran.    The two are not equivalent   (In fact, pointers operate differently in C++ and Fortran, and strings also work differently between C++ and Fortran).

Comment: I'm sure you understand my goal. What dodge can I use for that?

Comment: Of couse, I can't say that fortran has obviouse speed advantages. I only use simd parallelism "from the box", it's very comfortably for me.

Comment: I mean: (x, y) = (x0, y0)+k×(dx, dy) through xmm registers.

Comment: You probably want an allocatable object of some sort. But that's all I can really say - I don't understand what you are trying to do here. And please note the spelling of Fortran

Comment: I want to send my bitmap structure from c++ main.object to fortran_lib.object as ONE argument.

Comment: I can send my rgba× pointer (and other dynamic arrays)as separate arguments, but then my fortran function has about 10 parameters. It's not good, I think. When I send via structures my fortran function has only two parameters.

Comment: What language will operate on the data (as opposed to "just passing it around")? In what language is the main program? What are your hard constraints (some existing lib in C++ or Fortran, etc)?

Comment: There is no problem to mix c++ and assembler. In this case I can create 1 structure (with lot of pointers to arrays)and send it to assembler as 1 argument. But assembler is too hard. I want to do that with fortran.

Comment: Fortran doesn't allow me to create types whith free dimension arrays. That is my problem.

Comment: Thank you all. I'll try explane when I am at home.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use `TYPE` and `POINTER` in fortran to do what you can do with `struct` and `*` in C.

```
Program Bitmap_p
implicit none
type BitMap
character, pointer :: rgba(:) ! like a pointer to bitmap array (colors and alpha)
integer:: w  ! bitmap width
integer:: h  ! bitmap height
endtype BitMap

type(BitMap) :: bmap

bmap%w = 10
bmap%h = 10
allocate( bmap%rgba(4*bmap%w*bmap%h) )

endprogram Bitmap_p
```

Comment: Making the character array Allocatable rather than a pointer is most likely better style Fortran - pointers should be avoided wherever possible, allocatables avid a number of risks associated with them.

Comment: When possible, yes (and the same can be said for C++ char pointers). I assume the OP knows how to handle them in C++, and the same should work here.

Comment: @smval80 You're welcome. If you're satisfied with the answer, please [accept] it -- that's the SO way of saying thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much. But I don't know what size my array will have. I need to pass a completed structure (the structure created and initialized in c++ class) to the FORTRAN subroutine for performing it. If I pass arguments into FORTRAN subroutine not by structure but one by one, it will be list of about 12-15 arguments. For example: extern "C" plot_(sbmp *bmp, smatrix *matr, spoints *points), each of  thous structs has 2-3 pointers. What unit do I need to create in FORTRAN to operate with as argument to subroutine?

Comment: Sorry. I haven't understood yet haw to make [accept]. But I shall try.

Comment: Ah, the question indicates that you're re-writing all of the C code in Fortran. If you just want to call a Fortran function from C, see for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34561835/pass-arrays-from-c-c-to-fortran-and-return-a-calculated-array

Comment: Of course, that example works.  But there isn't any structs. I avoid large lists of arguments.

Comment: In addition. I use c++ for GUI (QTCreator) and FORTRAN for all math. FORTRAN can do simd parallelization "from the box".