# Can 3D arrays be passed between R/C and Fortran?

Tags: r, c, arrays, 3d, fortran

I am using a R/C wrapper to call a set of subroutines in a Fortran module. I want to get the outputs as arrays of 2D and 3D in R. However, I am having troubles defining the 3D output in the wrapper. So far I did not manage to define the output for a 3D array, since **allocMatrix** takes only three arguments (for 2D arrays/matrices):

```
SEXP output = PROTECT( allocMatrix(REALSXP, nt, 5) );   
// 2nd argument to allocMatrix is number of rows, 3rd is number of columns
```

Does anyone know if it is possible or how to define the output as a 3D array in the wrapper?

I'm working on a Mac running Fortran 90, GNU Fortran, and the C compiler that comes with Xcode.

Any help/suggestion would be much appreciated.

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34561835/pass-arrays-from-c-c-to-fortran-and-return-a-calculated-array) has something to say about this.  I am not sure if it will help.

Comment: Have you tried `SEXP Rf_alloc3DArray(SEXPTYPE, int, int, int);`?

Comment: One needs to get their head around the column major fortran and have some way to account for that differing from C being row major?